# Is there an service DHCP server for windows 10 iot?

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, dhcp

I've an Raspberry PI 3 with Windows 10 IoT. I'd like to run an DHCP server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a sample of DHCP server([enter link description here](https://github.com/Mike-McDonnell/sharp-dhcp-server-Windows-IoT)). It can works fine on my device.